# What are some network issues that could cause my file uploads to stall and fail?

Tags: networking, upload

I have a file uploader that is supposed to be used to upload video files to my company's website.

At the office, uploads consistently stall out(get stuck at a percentage and never move again, even if I let it sit for hours), or flat out fail.

When I attempt to upload a file from my home Internet connection, I have no issues. This makes me think there is something in our office's network configuration that is contributing to the problem.

I am certain we have enough bandwidth. We have a 20/20 fiber connection at the office. Whereas at home, I only have a 3/3 WISP connection.

Where can I begin looking to troubleshoot the problem? Should I start with the router/firewall? If so, I am not sure which settings I would want to look into.

I noticed that the request headers for the file upload contain the following lines, however, I have no idea how exactly these could be affecting the upload, if at all:

```
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 155155400
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----------GI3cH2Ef1ae0cH2ae0Ij5gL6ae0GI3
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
```

Any help at all is greatly appreciated.

-Jonathan

Comment: Probably someone is ~killing~ dropping the TCP connection, and the client can't reconnect. The headers look normal. Have you tried uploads to different sites? Is it all HTTP uploads, or just one specific server?

Comment: What protocol does your file uploader use? What are the upload limitations of your hosting site?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because your file uploader is trying to grab as much bandwidth as possible, and any delay (by a firewall, etc.) can stall it. Limiting the bandwidth to upload the files could help you.

In other hand, my first option will be look at the firewall, routers could have a firewall configured inside, or proxy configuration, maybe you have there some kind of limits about bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

The "uploads consistently stall out(get stuck at a percentage and never move again" makes me think that there is a timeout occurring.  Is the time the upload hangs the same for different files?   If yes, I'd immediately suspect something in the router, with NAT timeouts being my first look.